# Why does the jest mock function not getting executed in my test with react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

**The Problem**

I created a very basic code example for better clarification.
Here is the code I want to test (containing simple react hook):

```
const TodoHeader = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} data-testid="form">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Your Todo.."
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
        data-testid="input"
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

I want to test if the passed in `handleSubmit` prop will get executed. So I have set up this test:

```
it("should call the passed in onSubmit function", () => {
    const mockFn = jest.fn();

    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <TodoHeader handleSubmit={mockFn} />
    );
    const form = getByTestId("form");
    fireEvent.submit(form);
    // This will fail (did not get executed)
    expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Has it something to do with react hooks? I also tried to rerender it but same result.
I don't know why this won't pass. The error message is:

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Here is a codesandbox if you want to play around with it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ypok50n709
(`TodoHeader.js` and `TodoHeader.test.js`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a simple problem, `cleanup` isn't actually getting called in `afterEach`.  This means that there are two `form` elements rendered in `document` during the second test and `getByTestId` is returning the first one.

Change

```
afterEach(() => cleanup)
```

to either

```
afterEach(() => cleanup())
```

or just

```
afterEach(cleanup)
```

Comment: Interesting, note that this fixes the test in a dev environment but doesn't on the codesandbox...I wonder if it's some weird side effect from the browser trying to run `jsdom`.

Comment: Yep really weird. Thank you very much will check l8er and mark it as fixed.

Comment: I can confirm, that was the problem. Ofc I didn't call the function itself, so it hadn't cleaned up. That makes sense. Awesome man thx again!

Comment: FYI codesandbox has some issues running RTL. That's because the tests run in the browser and not in jsdom